# multer req.file is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I try to upload a file on my node js server using multer module, but for some reasons the uploaded file is always undefined. I have based my code using the documentation here https://github.com/expressjs/multer with the easy example for one single file.

Router :

```
var multerMiddleware = multer({"dest":"tmp/"});
var slidController = require('./../controllers/slid.controllers.js');

router.route('/slids')
.post(multerMiddleware.single('file'),slidController.create);
```

Controller :

```
SlidController.create = function(request,response) {
var id = Utils.generateUUID();
var fileName = Utils.getNewFileName(id,request.file.originalname);
var type = Utils.getFileType(request.file.mimetype);
var title = request.file.originalname;
//more code not relevant here
```

I use postman to send a post request with an image associated to the key "file", and still I always get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined", because obviously file is undefined.

Comment: Try req.files .When you are using array('filename') function it will gives an array of files in req.files .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding body-parser before multer :

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Multer config here ..
```

Your problem can also happen because you did not set the `Content-Type` header to `'multipart/form-data'` when sending your files

Or because there's no field `file` in your form.

Comment: actually I am trying to upload a jpeg image, so i was setting header to image/jpeg. using multipart/form-data throws me the error "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found"

Comment: well I am defining "file" as a key in the form, however maybe I am not correctly using postman.. here is a screenshot of my set-up (sry it is in french but I think it is still quite understandable) http://postimg.org/image/8om5tet8h/

Answer (score 0):

When you are running a curl request remember to give  instead of content-type data.